# How can I find the causes of a MySQL spike?

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I had a unusual spike in the number of MySQL queries in one of my servers. Is there any way I could inspect my logs to detect what was the main cause?

Thank you.

**Edit:** Added Munin graphs.!

[image: Munin graphs]

Comment: Sorry Patt, I don't understand your question. Could you please be a little more concise? Kind regards, Simon.

Comment: @Patt, I'm guessing Simon uses his eyes. Perhaps you intended to ask how the graphs are generated, or how is the data gathered (Munin apparently).

Answer (score 0):

The pt-query-digest tool from the [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/) will do this.